# Corrupted paths in Python 3.7 and it is possible restore/revert Python3.7 to it's original state? (19.04)

Tags: apt, package-management, python, software-uninstall

My `python3.7 paths` are corrupted. As I ended up installing `apt` and `pip3 packages,` from `virtualen`v, `wrapper`, `django`. Which is bad practice to install from `pip3`. I didn't back the files up properly. It ended causing issues in the `venv directory` and on `PyCharm IDE`. I tried uninstalling the third version of `virtualenv` and `django.` Which didn't make a difference.

So essentially revert `Python3.7` to to it's original state, no `extra packages installed etc.` 
                                                                                    `Terminal:`

```
python3

>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/name/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only one path to delete.

Here is what a stock install looks like:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
[
 '', 
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip', 
 '/usr/lib/python3.7', 
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', 
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'
]
```

Comment: Is the site-packages? I'm afraid of screwing it up. I C&P directly from the terminal and edited what it looks like in the terminal

Comment: You figured it out. Well done, have a cookie. Look at what's in that directory. Plan out how you want to uninstall that from your /home. Anything you want to keep, reinstall properly using the deb or pip in the proper system-wide locations.